# Select the 2 max values with GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I need to write a query that show the 2 max expensive order for every year and company.

I tried:

```
SELECT CompanyName, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS OrderYear, MAX(Freight)
FROM Orders, Shippers
WHERE Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipVia
GROUP BY CompanyName, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate)
```

But I get only the first, how can I get the second also?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results might help a bit ;-) @eliad choen

Comment: You mean the order that is 2nd max for the same year?

Comment: What if three orders have the same maximum amount?

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row number to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT CompanyName, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS OrderYear, Freight,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate)  ORDER BY Freight DESC) AS RN
  FROM Orders
  JOIN Shippers ON Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipVia
) X
WHERE X.RN < 3
```

Comment: I would use aliases there :)

Comment: @sami -- aliases where?

Comment: `ON S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia`

Comment: @sami -- oh I see.  well I was coping the style of the OP.